# Displaying current location and other locations on google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-api-3, gps

My code seperatly but crashes when i integrate!

this part work if i hard cod the value for current

```
Intent is = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmapcenter="+current+"&zoom=11&size=600000x400000&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:A%7C49.264081,-123.170326&markers=color:green%7Clabel:B%7C49.227741,-122.997605&markers=color:yellow%7Clabel:C%7C49.322642,-123.099007&markers=color:purple%7Clabel:E%7C49.267501,-123.000693&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:D%7C49.193767,-123.083017&sensor=false"));
startActivity(is);
```

This part works and gives current location

```
 googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
             LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
             String provider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
             Log.v(provider, "this is provider");
             if (provider == null){
                 onProviderDisabled(provider);
             }
             Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
             Log.v(loc.toString(),"this is loc");
             if(loc != null) {
                 onLocationChanged(loc);
```

But this one which is integration , crashes

```
     googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
     String provider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
     Log.v(provider, "this is provider");
     if (provider == null){
         onProviderDisabled(provider);
     }
     Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
     Log.v(loc.toString(),"this is loc");
     if(loc != null) {
         onLocationChanged(loc);
         String current= loc.toString();
                Intent is = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+current+"&zoom=11&size=600000x400000&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:A%7C49.264081,-123.170326&markers=color:green%7Clabel:B%7C49.227741,-122.997605&markers=color:yellow%7Clabel:C%7C49.322642,-123.099007&markers=color:purple%7Clabel:E%7C49.267501,-123.000693&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:D%7C49.193767,-123.083017&sensor=false"));
                startActivity(is);
```

LOGCAT:
04-04 20:58:34.765: W/dalvikvm(1082): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at com.example.distancemap.MainActivity.ShowMap(MainActivity.java:94)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at com.example.distancemap.MainActivity$TestGoogleMaps.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:67)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at com.example.distancemap.MainActivity$TestGoogleMaps.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-04 20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082):     ... 4 more

Comment: You may want to add logcat output to your question.

Comment: I just added the logcat

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clear. You have NPE in your code:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1082): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 04-04 
20:58:34.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1082): at 
com.example.distancemap.MainActivity.ShowMap(MainActivity.java:94)
```

Guessing this is your line 94:

```
Log.v(loc.toString(),"this is loc");
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. I'm pretty new . What is NPE and what should I do?

Comment: But the thing is it was working in separate why is it giving this error now

Comment: Which line is line number 94?

Comment: Then your problem is not integration and "This part works and gives current location" won't work either.